# How do I run the next method after getting the JSON data?

Tags: java, android

In general, if I receive JSONdata through an API call, the function will be executed in a separate thread through the override method.

Because of this, if I want to run the next method, I should write function code within the overridden response method.

but Instead of doing this, I want to pass the data to another fragment and use the data in another fragment.

The problem is that the function does not execute sequentially due to the responese method being executed separately, so a nullpoint error occurs in the part receiving the next fragment.

What do you usually do in this case?

```
private void getDataWtd(String type, String url) {

    // instantiate and initialize volley requestQueue
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    // instantiate jsonObjectRequest
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            // extract timeSeries part of the JSON
            Log.i("test", "onResponse: "+response);
            JSONObject jsonObject = getTimeSeries(response);

            if(type.equals("intra")){
                jsonObjectIntra = jsonObject;

            }else {
                jsonObjectHistory = jsonObject;
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("test", "Something went wrong: "+ error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to perform request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: add your code so that we can understand your problem?

Comment: Why can't you just execute the `FragmentTransaction` from `onResponse()`? It's no different than calling any other method. You can even put it in its own method, if you like.

Comment: Use retrofit library ,Retrofit performs and handles the method execution in a separated thread.

Comment: I am going to store jsonObject, and use these data in several fragment in viewpager. so I try to pass data to other fragment.

Comment: OK, that's fine, too. I read your question as saying you were passing arguments to a new `Fragment`, but it's still the same deal. Execute whatever code you're using to pass the JSON data from `onResponse()`.

Comment: I thought I was wrong for a while. your answer is correct. I changed the way that creation of all fragments is performed within the response method. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Try Something like this**

```
  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", "your data here");

    final OneFragment one= new AllFragment();
    final TwoFragment two= new BeautyFragment();

    one.setArguments(bundle);
    two.setArguments(bundle);

    adapter.addFragment(one, "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(two, "TWO");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

---

**In your fragment**

```
  Bundle  bundle = this.getArguments();
  String data= bundle.getString("key");
```